# Invalid Email addrss - Hg git

Tags: git, mercurial, tortoisehg

Why do I get `"Invalid Email Address"` when commiting to GitHub through TortoiseHg Hg-git plugin? The push works fine, however the email address is invalid.

I have tried many "solutions":

Add this to `hgrc`:

```
[ui]
username = Xybrek <xybrek@myemail.com>
```

And also adding this to the global TortoiseHg `mercurial.ini`

I also have tried adding authors.txt in my project's path

Then add this line in the `hgrc`

```
[git]
authors = authors.txt
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2477804/157 mentions the order of files that are looked at in Windows. It should be, `.hgrc`. My guess is that one of the files it checks first is invalid, so no matter what you do it wont solve the problem until you change that file.

Comment: Right, however the hgrc file contains the [ui] username = 
on it

Comment: It should be `.hgrc` in your home, or `hgrc` file within the repo. Where is the file you're talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942196/hggit-invalid-email-address-at-github

Comment: @davidmc24 Yah this is a possible duplicate; but answers in the question don't work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`authors.txt` should be located in the root of the repository.

Don't forget to clear a cached git repo:

```
$ hg gclear
```